# java. nio. connect multiple channels to one selector

Tags: java, client-server, selector, nio, channel

I am trying to understand how to write simplest application with one selector and multiple channels.

After incredible effort I was able to write following code:

server:

```
private static byte[] data = new byte[255];

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
            data[i] = (byte) i;

        ServerSocketChannel server = ServerSocketChannel.open();
        server.configureBlocking(false);

        server.socket().bind(new InetSocketAddress(9000));
        Selector selector = Selector.open();
        server.register(selector, SelectionKey.OP_ACCEPT);

        while (true) {
            selector.select();
            Set readyKeys = selector.selectedKeys();
            Iterator iterator = readyKeys.iterator();
            while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                SelectionKey key = (SelectionKey) iterator.next();
                iterator.remove();
                if (key.isAcceptable()) {
                    SocketChannel client = server.accept();
                    System.out.println("Accepted connection from " + client);
                    client.configureBlocking(false);
                    ByteBuffer source = ByteBuffer.wrap(data);
                    SelectionKey key2 = client.register(selector, SelectionKey.OP_WRITE);
                    key2.attach(source);
                } else if (key.isWritable()) {
                    SocketChannel client = (SocketChannel) key.channel();
                    ByteBuffer output = (ByteBuffer) key.attachment();
                    if (!output.hasRemaining()) {
                        output.rewind();
                    }
                    client.write(output);
                }
                key.channel().close();
            }
        }
    }
```

client(sender):

```
public static void main(String[] argv) throws Exception {
        SocketChannel sChannel = SocketChannel.open();
        sChannel.configureBlocking(false);
        sChannel.connect(new InetSocketAddress("localhost", 9000));

        ByteBuffer buf = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(1024);
        buf.put((byte) 0xFF);

        buf.flip();

        int numBytesWritten = sChannel.write(buf);
    }
```

my steps:

> 1. run server
> 2. run client

After this step in server console I see following:

```
Accepted connection from java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[connected local=/127.0.0.1:9000 remote=/127.0.0.1:49184]
```

In client console I see following:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.nio.channels.NotYetConnectedException
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.ensureWriteOpen(SocketChannelImpl.java:269)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.write(SocketChannelImpl.java:474)
    at io.nio.SocketSender.main(SocketSender.java:25)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)
```

Please help to understand the reason of stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

The message is clear enough. I would do the client connect in blocking mode: then it either completes or fails. Otherwise you have to use a Selector, select for OP_CONNECT, use finishConnect(), test its return value, etc. In fact I would use blocking mode through the client, and I probably wouldn't use NIO at all.